# is it possible to change iterator type ? of iterator created from classes that implemets interface

Tags: java, iterator

is it possible to cast like this ?

```
Iterator<Class that implemets the interface> -->  Iterator<Interface>
```

i have this member in my Algo Class

```
 public HashMap<Integer, HashMap<NodeC, EdgeC>> edges;
```

on this function i am generating an iterator type `<EdgeData>` is need to return but the problem is that i am working with classes spesipclly with Edge Class so it throw an error

```
    @Override
    public Iterator<EdgeData> edgeIter(int node_id) {
 
       
            return this.edges.get(node_id).values().iterator();
        
      
    }
```

````
Incompatible types. Found: 'java.util.Iterator<src.api.Edge>', required: 'java.util.Iterator<src.interfaces.EdgeData>'```
````

program about graphs

structure

```
interfaces
  |-->  EdgeData
  |-->  Algo    

Classes 
  |--> Edge implements EdgeData
  |--> AlgoClass implements Algo
```

in my AlgoClass i am using a ***HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Node,Edge>> edges***;

so that i get an edge in o(1) by first passing the source of the edge and then every Node has a hashmap inside of it of the destenations , so by passing the destenation i will get the correct Edge ! in o(1) approximitly .

***problem is with the return type of the Iterator in edgeIter function , i need it to be EdgeData type like the interface EdgeData.
and i dont know if it is possible to cast the Iterator to Iterator.***

Comment: Side note: You should use `Map<Integer, Map<Node, Edge>>`. Code to the interface, not the implementation.

Comment: Even better, change it to `Map<Integer, Map<Node, EdgeData>>` and then your iterator will naturally be an `Iterator<EdgeData>`.

Comment: thats what i ended up doing ; the problem was an edge contains this members , src , dest , weight , and i was using the src as the key for the map , and ended up running over values if i had the same src , so i Switched to ```Map<String, Map<Node, EdgeData>>``` and now i am saving the key as ```"src_" + src + "_dest_" + dest :)```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the return type to `Iterator<? extends EdgeData>`.

If you can't change that interface, you have to work around the bug (because that signature is just plain wrong). You can, with uglycasting. It'll generate warnings that you have to then suppress. Just cast to `Iterator<EdgeData>`.

Comment: how can i just cast to Iterator<EdgeData> ?

Comment: i know how to cast a class like this (EdgeData) Edge

Comment: but i dont know how to cast Iterator<Edge> to Iterator<EdgeData>

Comment: i cant touch the interface

Comment: Same syntax: Iterator<EdgeData> foo = (Iterator<EdgeData>) bar;

Comment: wish someone told me that before :)

Comment: add this syntax to the answer

Comment: the syntax does not works ```  Cannot cast from Iterator<NodeC> to Iterator<NodeData>Java(16777372)
 ```

Comment: Dolev, I told you to just change the signature to `Iterator<? extends NodeData>` - an `Iterator<ChildClass>` just isn't the same as an `Iterator<Parent>` - you can hack it: `Iterator a = ...; Iterator raw = a; Iterator<ParentClass> b = raw;` will do it. As can casting to the raw type and then to the right type in a row, but, this is just enabling bad behaviour.